# Windows Task Scheduler Failing To Stop Exe

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, vmware

When I run a CMD-called Robocopy job (which we use to back up two folders nightly with the /MIR to increment changes) the scheduled task itself fails to completely stop the Robocopy process.
When the allotted time to run in task scheduler has been reached, the task set also only shows "Stopping" but never "Stopped", but the Robocopy still has more to do... Shouldn't the Task Scheduler stop the Robocopy?
[image]

ALL of this is running over VMWARE 5... (not that this has anything really to do with it)
The Robocopy job is a simple /MIR; Here are the switches:
`/MIR /R:5 /V /NP /LOG path\file.log`

All servers are Windows 2012R2 (One Server backs up the other to itself, which is then fully backed up nightly with Veritas NetBackup.

Answer (score 0):

If the task is scheduled to run a script firing the robocopy process, I would suggest to create another scheduled task with a script to terminate the already running robocopy process

Answer (score 0):

## Windows Task Scheduler Failing To Stop Exe

### Answer: Robocopy ***directly*** with PowerShell - *do not call a cmd/batch file*

```
#Robocopy folders with Mirror - Delete what you want to manually
$JobName = Read-Host -Prompt "Name the Job"
$OLDPATH= Read-Host -Prompt "What folder to move? - full path or UNC"
$OLDPATH.toLower()
$NEWPATH= Read-Host -Prompt "Destination of the folder? - full path or UNC"
$NEWPATH.toLower()
robocopy $OLDPATH $NEWPATH *.* /MIR /PURGE /R:5 /MT:128 /V /NP /LOG:D:\Batch\Log\$day-$JobName-Robocopy.log
```

> In case you didn't notice, Robocopy has a HIDDEN option called >"Multi-Threading" - '/mt:128', 128 is the highest number. BOY, did >that save me allot of time! -Patrick